# Can't access log files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ubuntu, permissions, production

I was trying to run my application and check for some output on the production.log. However [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) throws this error.
Apache log

`Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /var/www/somefolder/someapp/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.`

I have performed the necessary chmod 666 production.log to make it work but I realized that the file is under root access.

So my file permissions are

`-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root  20845 2010-03-18 01:18 production.log`

I'm not sure how to allow Ruby on Rails to access this file. I'm fairly new to managing a Linux production environment so I request you to excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I need to find my production.log files.... Don't know where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to change the user and group of production.log to whatever user and group Rails (i.e. Passenger or Mongrel or whatever you are using) runs under.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I just figured it out.

First need to update Apache.conf passenger configurations:

`PassengerDefaultUser username`

The assign ownership using chown:

`chown -R username:username <folder>`

I don't know if this is the right way but it worked for me.