# Ruby on Rails Setup: Unable to access log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, ubuntu

I'm setting up Ruby on Rails for the first time; on my server, I've created and loaded the default rails app. I can view the default page ("Welcome aboard! You are riding Rails"), but when I go to click on the link to "View Application Environment", it generates a 500 error.

(You can view it [here](http://test.delner.com).)

I'd like to know more about the error, but, the log file ("log/production.log") is empty. Looking at my Apache log I find:

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that
>   /var/www/rails/myapp/log/production.log exists and is chmod 0666. The
>   log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR
>   until the problem is fixed.

So, I actually want to get my Ruby on Rails error logging working.

I know this problem has been posted a few times before, but I tried everything I could find, so here's what I have tried:

1. Created the "log/production.log" file, set the owner to www-data, set `chmod 0666`.
2. Set the owner of the "log" folder to `www-data`, set `chmod 0666`.
3. Double-checked my production environment settings such that `config.log_level = :info` is set.
4. Checked that Apache is using the www-data user ("etc/apache2/envvars"):

   ```
   export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data
   export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data
   ```
5. "etc/apache2/mods-available/passenger.conf" has a default user set for Passenger:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /usr
     PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
     PassengerDefaultUser www-data
   </IfModule>
   ```
6. The owner of "config.ru" and "configs/environment.rb" is `www-data`
7. My virtual host has been set accordingly:

   ```
   DocumentRoot /var/www/rails/myapp/public
   RackBaseURI /
   RackEnv production
   PassengerMaxPoolSize 4
   ```

Already read and attempted all the fixes suggested in these places:

- [Rails: Unable to access log file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632592/rails-unable-to-access-log-file)
- [Can't access log files in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469059/cant-access-log-files-in-production)
- http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=36168
- [Why am I getting Permission denied error in deployment on files generated by capistrano?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433569/why-am-i-getting-permission-denied-error-in-deployment-on-files-generated-by-cap)
- http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/a-sneaky-rails-3-bug-in-logging/

(That's all I can remember trying right now...)

Some environment settings of mine:

- Ubuntu 11.10 running on Amazon EC2
- Apache 2.2.20
- RVM 1.10.2
- Ruby 1.9.3p0
- Rails 3.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved now, though the the cause of the problem itself isn't entirely clear.

I had some weird configuration issues with Apache & Passenger (a.k.a. ModRails). Two modules existed: one that appeared to come packaged with Apache(?) and one I obtained via `passenger-install-apache2-module`. When I pointed to the pre-installed one, I had this logging issue. When I pointed to the one deployed by `passenger-install-apache2-module`, I had a completely different issue where Passenger would crash with a segfault (see my post on ServerFault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/351651/modrails-for-apache2-setup-failing-to-load/351927).)

In the end, I completely wiped my server and performed a clean install of everything from the base Ubuntu AMI (running on Amazon EC2 made this easy enough.) Upon reinstalling, I ran `passenger-install-apache2-module` and configured Apache to load the module deployed by it. This time, the module didn't crash, but the log error appeared. I set `chmod 755` on the root of my Rails application, made sure the production.log existed and that it had at least `chmod 0666` privileges. And voila, problem gone.

**TL;DR** Did a fresh install, made sure I was using the latest Passenger module, and my file permissions were set properly.